# Making Springboot application Pod to be deleted automatically

Tags: spring-boot, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to deploy Springboot application on Kubernetese and I don't want Pod to run endlessly. As soon as the process gets finised, I want pod to be terminated by itself. Now, because of some business logic, we are generating token at each 45 minutes interval using `@Scheduled(FixedRateString...)` in our Springboot application, it means the process would keep running. To make sure our process gets terminated, we are using `System.exit(0)` at the end of the application.

I deployed code using below deployment.yml file. As soon as the process is getting terminated, I am seeing the new Pod getting up again , how can I make sure it gets terminate/deleted automatically as soon as the process finished.

**deployment.yml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    tier: pred-d
    app: test-prov-img
  name: test-prov-img
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-prov-img
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-prov-img
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: docker.repo1.com/apps/test-prov-img:1.2
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: test-prov-img
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: service
              protocol: TCP
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: configmap
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 1.25Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 0.1
              memory: 0.25Gi
```

Please suggest what changes I have to do in the deployment.yml to make the Pod termianted/deleted automatically.

Comment: Does your pod do anything else, apart from just running that `@Scheduled` method?

Comment: Yes, there is whole business logic, getting records from database, call API with token to update records into a table..

Comment: I'm a little confused about what it's actually meant to do. Does it do as much work as it can in 45 minutes and then die, whether it's actually completed its work or not?

Comment: The API that we are using works with a token and this token has self life of 45 minutes.. So, if the processing goes beyond 45 minutes, we need to generate a new token to continue our processing..

Answer (score 1):

A method annotated with `@Scheduled` is designed to repeat. Instead of scheduling something, just make the application do whatever it needs to do and then finish. One option can be to add a `CommandLineRunner` implementation that performs the work that is currently being done by the `@Scheduled` method.

```java
@Component
public class TaskPerformer implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    // @Scheduled(fixedRateString = ...) We no longer need this
    public void run(String... args) {
        // TODO: Generate token here
    }
}
```

Then, you can convert your application into a [Kubernetes CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) which you can instruct to run every 45 minutes. That `CronJob` will then start up on time, run the application which generates a token, and then shut itself down.

Comment: Thanks for the response Thomas !! Please check my response in your comment.  We are planning to use CronJob to schedule this complete application as whole application needs to run daily on certain time. And, once it runs , it need to process records using API + Token (wait for 45 mins and generate new one after 45 mins).. so I am not sure whether cronjob would work for token..

Comment: Okay - not to pick too much on your architecture, but wouldn't it make much more sense to actually have new tokens issued until the entire task is finished? If you're using some sort of OAuth2.0 token issuer then Spring Boot has a pretty good project you can plug into your project. It will then take care of token generation for you based on the tokens' `exp` claims.

Comment: In any case, I don't know of anything you can do to your `Deployment` manifest to kill the application after 45 minutes, without using a `CronJob`. And if you can't do it from outside the application, you need to do it from within. The only options that come to mind are doing it like you've done, or kill the application when you start receiving HTTP 401 from the API you're calling (just keep transaction management in mind).